# How to create a Perl debugger

Tags: linux, perl, debugging

I wrote a bunch of functions for the Perl debugger, but every time I want to test them I need to do `export PERL5DB="my code"`. Is there a way I can set it to a file and then use it?

I tried adding a file `myperldb.pl` in `/usr/lib/perl/`, but it doesn't allow me. That's because I am not the administrator user. So is there a workaround to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a copy of `/usr/lib/perl/perl5db.pl` in some other directory, change it to your heart's content, and debug your scripts with

```
perl -I/dir/that/contains/your/perl5db.pl/copy/ -d your_script.pl
```

The `-I<dir>` switch will get perl to look in the directory you choose to find libraries before it looks in its default directories.

Comment: I don't have the file /usr/lib/perl/perl5db.pl

Comment: Run `perldoc -l perl5db.pl` to see where it is.

Comment: can you provide me with the file in your system. I am using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2):

That's what the [`.perldb` file](http://p3rl.org/debug) is for.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this command:

`PERL5DB="BEGIN{ require 'my_debugger.pm' }" perl -d script.pl`

```
$cat my_debugger.pm
package DB;

sub DB {
}

sub sub {
        print "$DB::sub called\n";

        return &$DB::sub;
}


1;
```

You may find more information [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebguts.html#Writing-Your-Own-Debugger).